# Django testing - spoofing an Ajax POST request method with Client() to pass request.is_ajax() validation

Tags: django, django-tests

Not sure if this is possible, but I have the following validation check for an Ajax POST request in my `views.py`:

```
if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
    # Do some amazing stuff here...
    context['is_ajax'] = True
```

Now, running a few tests in the shell:

```
from django.test import Client
>>> c = Client()
>>> response = c.post('/login/', {'username': 'john', 'password': 'smith'})
>>> response.context['is_ajax']
>>> undefined
```

So my question is, is there a way with the test Client to spoof an Ajax request...passing the `is_ajax()` validation check on the request POST object, is this done by  adding something to headers?

I think the header should be `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest'` - how would this be passed in to the `c.post()` method?

Answer (score 0):

So in your case it will be something like this

```
response = c.post('/login/', {'username': 'john', 'password': 'smith'},
                          HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest')
```

hope that points you in the right direction.